# Efficient use of the GAE DataStore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am currently developing a Google AppEngine (GAE) application and I am struggling a bit with the GAE DataStore best practices. I would like to use the DataStore in the most efficient way. I am using the Objectify framework, but am flexible to use something else if there is a better alternative.

My application uses three objects/tables:
- Items (id, description)
- List (id, listId, listDescription
- SecurityProfile (id,listId, username, accessType)

I an relational world, my Items and SecurityProfiles tables would have an external key to link them to a list (ListId) and I would then use joins in my queries.

The typical Queries I need to make:
- Get all lists accessible to a particular user (need an index on "username" to filter by username and need to get the description from the List table)
- Get all items in list for a particular user (get the Items linked to the Lists retrieved in the query above)

I am struggling a bit to come up with a way to link the different objects in an efficient way (minimizing the DataStore queries and indexes).

I have seen in other posts that joins should be avoided and that I should de-normalize the model as much as possible.

So kind of creating one object only:
- Data (id, description, listId, listDescription, username, accessType)

I can see how that work from a read point of view, but if I update a listDescription, an accessType or add a new username, I could potentially have to update a massive amount of records. Is this really the way to go ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GAE : How to map object oriented designs into Appengine datastore efficiently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278805/gae-how-to-map-object-oriented-designs-into-appengine-datastore-efficiently)

Answer (score 1):

I'm only familiar with the Python NDB API, but things are similar in Java.

In [Python NDB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/), I would recommend to create a Model for each

- User,
- List,
- List item

Then, you can reference them with *[repeated](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#repeated)* KeyProperties, e.g.

```
class SecurityProfiles(ndb.Model):
    accessibleLists = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=true)

class List(ndb.Model):
    listItems = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=true)
```

Like this, you can pull a user's profile from the DataStore, and with the keys stored in `accessibleLists` you can get the lists accessible to the user.

Alternatively, you could do it the other way around:

```
class List(ndb.Model):
    usersWithAccess = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=true)
```

and then you could immediately query for lists that are accessible to a given user.

Comment: Thank you for the example. Is there something similar available in Java (ideally in Objectify) ?

Comment: I believe the underlying Datastore is the same, no matter what API you use. So there should be similar functionality in Java. But I haven't used Java on GAE yet.